# Emit of explicit method override hides property

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

There is a class with one property:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I create a derived type with some method overrides:

```
[Test]
public void name ()
{
  var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly (new AssemblyName ("Test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
  var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule ("Test.dll");
  var derivedBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType ("DerivedClass", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof (BaseClass));

  const MethodAttributes methodAttributes = MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.NewSlot;

  var getterOverride = derivedBuilder.DefineMethod (
      "get_Property1",
      methodAttributes,
      typeof (string),
      Type.EmptyTypes);
  var getterILGenerator = getterOverride.GetILGenerator();
  getterILGenerator.Emit (OpCodes.Ldnull);
  getterILGenerator.Emit (OpCodes.Ret);
  derivedBuilder.DefineMethodOverride (getterOverride, typeof (BaseClass).GetMethod ("get_Property1"));

  var setterOverride = derivedBuilder.DefineMethod (
      "set_Property1",
      methodAttributes,
      typeof (void),
      new[] { typeof (string) });
  var setterILGenerator = setterOverride.GetILGenerator ();
  setterILGenerator.Emit (OpCodes.Ret);
  derivedBuilder.DefineMethodOverride (setterOverride, typeof (BaseClass).GetMethod ("set_Property1"));

  var derivedType = derivedBuilder.CreateType();
  var props = derivedType.GetProperties (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

  assemblyBuilder.Save ("Test.dll");

  Assert.That (props, Has.Length.EqualTo (1));
}
```

The generated type doesn't contain the property anymore. Curiously the property appears again if you change the `methodAttributes` to `MethodAttributes.Public` for at least one method definition.

Seems like a bug?

**Edit:** peverify doesn't give an error.

**Edit:** (important comment of Fabian Schmied)

ECMA-335 Partition II, 10.3.3: "If a type overrides an inherited method via a MethodImpl, it can widen or narrow the accessibility of that method."

Comment: Property1 is a public property in BaseClass hence it will show up with MethodAttributes.Public

Comment: Did you verify the generated assembly? Many spec violations get caught by PEVerify, but not if you simply load the code.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: peverify doesn't give an error

Comment: @FabianSchmied You've convinced me, I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Just for completeness, I'll repeat my comment here: ECMA-335 Partition II, 10.3.3: "If a type overrides an inherited method via a MethodImpl, it can widen or narrow the accessibility of that method." So, the sample doesn't seem to produce illegal code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [specs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFYQFjAB&url=http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf&ei=0hMhUN7FK5L74QSTyIGYDw&usg=AFQjCNFVe1ujQC6xdlnJU5pRFAZGVfbc0Q) (ECMA-335, II.10.3.3) explicitly allow one to narrow the visibility of methods overridden via a MethodImpl ("explicit overrides", expressed by Reflection.Emit via TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride), I believe this is indeed a bug in the Reflection implementation and should be reported via [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: [Bug report on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757478/overriding-a-propertys-accessor-via-a-methodimpl-can-cause-the-property-to-disappear-from-reflection)